# Cache files are gone in my GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup GitLab CI for a mono repository.

For the sake of the argument, lets say I want to process 2 JavaScript packages:

- app
- cli

I have defined 3 stages:

- install
- test
- build
- deploy

Because I'm reusing the files from previous steps, I use the GitLab cache.

My configuration looks like this:

```
stages:
  - install
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

install_app:
  stage: install
  image: node:8.9
  cache:
    policy: push
    paths:
      - app/node_modules
  script:
    - cd app
    - npm install

install_cli:
  stage: install
  image: node:8.9
  cache:
    policy: push
    paths:
      - cli/node_modules
  script:
    - cd cli
    - npm install

test_app:
  image: node:8.9
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - app/node_modules
  script:
    - cd app
    - npm test

test_cli:
  image: node:8.9
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - cli/node_modules
  script:
    - cd cli
    - npm test

build_app:
  stage: build
  image: node:8.9
  cache:
    paths:
      - app/node_modules
      - app/build
  script:
    - cd app
    - npm run build

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/my/gcloud/image
  only:
    - master
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://example.com
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - app/build
  script:
    - gcloud app deploy app/build/app.yaml
        --verbosity info
        --version master
        --promote
        --stop-previous-version
        --quiet
        --project "$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"
```

The problem is in the test stage. Most of the time the `test_app` job fails, because the `app/node_modules` directory is missing. Sometimes a retry works, but mostly not.

Also, I would like to use two caches for the `build_app` job. I want to pull `app/node_modules` and push `app/build`. I can't find a way to accomplish this. This makes me feel like I don't fully understand how the cache works.

Why are my cache files gone? Do I misunderstand how GitLab CI cache works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cache is provided on a best-effort basis, so don't expect that the cache will be always present.**

If you have hard dependencies between jobs, use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts) and [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#dependencies).

Anyway, if it is just for `node_modules`, I suggest you to install it in every step, instead of using artifacts - you will not save much time with artifacts.

Comment: I have 350MB in node_modules. I bet with cache from GitLab´s own network (on digital ocean I guess) as one zip package would be quite a bit faster than fetching separate ( +3000 ) packages independently.

Also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#good-caching-practices lists that GitLab.com uses distributed caching.

Caches are uploaded to S3 if distributed cache is enabled. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#cache-vs-artifacts

That would lead me to believe caches would be shared between runners. The error might be due to distributed cache running out of space.

Comment: Yea these cache feature in Gitlab CI doesn't work in my opinion, its either not restoring the cache or using the cache and in all cases it's way too slow..